# How do I explicitly raise exception in celery periodic task scheduler?

Tags: python, flask, cron, celery, scheduler

I have worked with celery few time, Whenever I try to raise an exception in celery periodic task exception does not raise. Am I missing something?
I only get small message, but exception does not explain anything in details also no trace back.

```
from celery.exceptions import CeleryError


@celery.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):

    try:
        winbeat_time_data = extract_time_data(WINBEAT_TIME_DATA)
        ftp_tim_data = extract_time_data(FTP_TIME_DATA)


        sender.add_periodic_task(300, heart_beat.s(), name='Heart Beat')
        sender.add_periodic_task(
            int(RETRY_INTERVAL), retry_failed_upload,  name='RETRY_FAILED_UPLOAD')

        sender.add_periodic_task(
            crontab(hour=ftp_tim_data["hour"], minute=ftp_tim_data["minute"], day_of_week=ftp_tim_data["day_of_week"]),
            upload_file.s(),
            name='File Upload')

        sender.add_periodic_task(crontab(hour=winbeat_time_data["hou"], minute=winbeat_time_data["minute"],
                             day_of_week=winbeat_time_data["day_of_week"]), generate_winbeat.s(), name='Generate Winbeat')
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR:-->", e)
        raise CeleryError(f'Celery task faile with error{e}')
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code in my own project before `def setup_periodic_tasks(`

```py
from functools import wraps
from celery.utils.dispatch.signal import Signal


def send_add_raise_exc(send):
    @wraps(send)
    def send_raise_exc(*args, **kwargs):
        responses = send(*args, **kwargs)
        for _, exc_or_resp in responses:
            if isinstance(exc_or_resp, BaseException):
                raise exc_or_resp
        return responses
    return send_raise_exc


Signal.send = send_add_raise_exc(Signal.send)


@celery.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    pass
```